# process input arguments to a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, arguments

I'm processing files with a bash script `$ processh.sh file`. The input `file` contains information about the files to process

```
# id path type
id1 filename1 csv
id2 filename2 
id3 filename3 json
...
```

`process.sh` is sth like

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
parse(x) {
    # get idX filenameX typeX
    # check if filenameX exists on disk
    # if typeX is missing, set to csv
}
a=`grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)' $1`  # remove comment and empty lines
echo $a | while IFS= read -r l; do
    [id, filename, type]=parse(l)
    process filenameX ...
done
```

How do I make the sanity checks as commented above in the code?

Comment: Very little of that is useful code, I'm afraid. What do you want to do with the three values from each line once you've validated them?

Comment: See [BashFAQ #1: "How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?", especially the field-splitting section](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Field_splitting.2C_whitespace_trimming.2C_and_other_input_processing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you next solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

parse() {
        # get idX filenameX typeX
        id=$1
        filename=$2
        typo=$3

        # if typeX is missing, set to csv
        [ -z "$typo" ] && typo="csv"

        # check if filenameX exists on disk
        [ -f "$filename.$typo" ] && echo "Filename $filename exists"
}

while IFS= read -r line
do
        parse_line=`echo $line | grep -vE '^(\s*$|#)'`
        [ ! -z "$parse_line" ] && parse $parse_line
done < "$1"
```